# Validation error during the update of codepipeline via AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, aws-codepipeline

I have been trying to use the update functionality of the AWS CLI to update codepipeline with the following command:

```
aws codepipeline update-pipeline --cli-input-json file://Pipelines/AWS/SomeName.json
```

And I keep getting the following error

```
Unknown parameter in pipeline.stages[0].actions[0]: "region", must be one of: name, actionTypeId, runOrder, configuration, outputArtifacts, inputArtifacts, roleArn
```

I have checked the documentation for AWS and I don´t think theres anything wrong with the way actions is set up, here is the snippet from JSON:

```
"actions": [
                    {
                        "name": "Source",
                        "actionTypeId": {
                            "category": "Source",
                            "owner": "AWS",
                            "provider": "S3",
                            "version": "1"
                        },
                        "runOrder": 1,
                        "configuration": {
                            "PollForSourceChanges": "false",
                            "S3Bucket": "some-bucket-name",
                            "S3ObjectKey": "someEnvironment/someZip.zip"
                        },
                        "outputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "SourceArtifact"
                            }
                        ],
                        "inputArtifacts": [],
                        "region": "eu-west-1"
                    },...
]
```

According to the documentation provided at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-S3.html
everything seems to be correct. Removing the region parameter updates the pipeline correctly but I am unsure of the consequences that could have on the updates itself

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers
Sky

Answer (score 0):

If you try to create the pipeline through the AWS console and choose S3 as a source you will notice the region option is not available (as shown in the screenshot below). I would say this is a current limitation to the service more then a chosen design and a gap in documentation (however, happy to be proven wrong).

However, you could try include the full [S3 bucket Arn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-arn-format.html) which would include the region. Or take comfort in that any action deployed (without a region specified) defaults to the same region that the codepipeline is in, as per the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-create-cross-region.html).

[image]